# Having problems with DatePicker in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, datepicker

I am trying to convert the LocalDate coming from Datepicker but having issues with it. Below is the code related to DatePicker. I am using FXML. This should be self contained example. The output of the dates is something like this

Date String is :17Feb2015
DateString converted to date is :Sun Dec 28 00:00:00 IST 2014
Local date converted to date is :Tue Feb 17 00:00:00 IST 2015

As you can see date changed in conversion, from LocalDate to Date to String to Date

## Controller

```
public class ReportViewerController implements Initializable {
@FXML
private DatePicker datepickerfx1;
@FXML
private DatePicker datepickerfx2;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
//    LocalDate date = datepickerfx1.getValue();


       datepickerfx1.setOnAction(event -> {
        LocalDate date = datepickerfx1.getValue();
        Instant instant = date.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
        Date res = Date.from(instant);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMYYYY");
        String       pexpdateStr= dateFormat.format(res);
        Date newdate=null;
           try {
               newdate = dateFormat.parse(pexpdateStr);
           } catch (ParseException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(ReportViewerController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
        System.out.println("Date String is :"+pexpdateStr);
         System.out.println("DateString converted to date is :" +newdate);

        System.out.println("Local date converted to date is :"+res);

           });  
}    

}
```

## FXML File

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testbed.ReportViewerController">
  <center>
  <GridPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
     <children>
        <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
           <children>
              <DatePicker fx:id="datepickerfx1" />
              <DatePicker fx:id="datepickerfx2" />
           </children>
        </HBox>
       </children>
      </GridPane>
    </center>
  </BorderPane>
```

## main file

```
public class TestBed extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ReportViewer.fxml"));

   Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, screenBounds.getWidth()/3, screenBounds.getHeight()/3);
    scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the code jay :-)
The problem is quite simple but deceptive and has to do with this line:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMYYYY");
```

If you read the docs for SimpleDateFormat carefully then you will notice that there is a difference between a capital **Y** and a little **y**.

Big Y is for which year does a week belong too, and is only really relevant for the dates that are in the first and last weeks of a year.

Now the docs say "*If week year 'Y' is specified and the calendar doesn't support any week years, the calendar year ('y') is used instead.*"  so that's why you get the expected result for `pexpdateStr`.

However it seems as though this rule doesn't apply when parsing back and so you get the 'incorrect' result for `newdate`.

So what you meant was "ddMMMyyyy" and not "ddMMMYYYY", a simple mistake, which will remove the inconsistency.

Comment: Arghhhhh .. stupid me. Having DD and YYYY a few places in date picker and that is causing the mess up. Thanks Sir for guiding me on the right path. One more question, why isnt the date showing up in yyyy-MM-dd format and instead showing up as Tue Feb 17 00:00:00 IST 2015. How can I get that without converting into string. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: The yyyy-MM-dd format is what you get from `java.sql.Date`